# Unding Macro actions made during a SlideShow

Tags: vba, events, powerpoint, slideshow, undo

I want to ask about something, that can probably get pretty complex. I'm working on an interactive presentation with some game elements (stuff that use variables, a timer, score, etc.) and I've noticed that any changes a macro makes (changing the string in a text box, disabling certain shapes) when you run a slide show remain after the slide show has finished. Given that the presentation and the games therein are made to be played multiple times, I would like to avoid having the user click "Undo" a million times or closing and opening the presentation again. I am not sure how to go about this, but I've had a few ideas:

The first one was to track every change that's being made, while the game is running and then have a macro use the "Undo" command the required number of times, once the slideshow is stopped. Creating an Event Handler however proved to be rather complicated. I'm not that well versed in VBA and reading how many declarations, classes and whatnot have to be made, the fact that I cannot find in the reference what the Event for simply ending the slideshow is (that is, when the user presses Esc, not when the last slide has been reached) not to mention the fact that it's very easy to make a mistake that can render all of that code useless, makes me think this is needlessly complicated just for a single event.

Another idea was to set the initial values of the properties that are to be changed during the game, along with the needed variables at the start of the game, so that no matter what changes are made in the presentation, the values will always be reset when running it, although that would make it tedious to tweak things and make big changes to the game, when needed.

Can you give me some suggestions on how I should go about this problem? Which method would be better? Is there some way to make it so that nothing a macro does during a slide show makes actual changes to the presentation itself? I'd very much like to hear your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: What about saving it prior to start and reverting afterwards?

Comment: Hm, creating a copy before start, showing it and deleting afterwards and coming back to original presentation ?

Comment: Those are interesting suggestions, though I'm afraid they will require the event handler for exiting the slideshow. Is there a simple way to create it? Can someone please explain how the declaration works?  Why do I need a separate class module and all that?

Comment: To capture events, you need the WithEvents keyword, which is only valid in a class module. An event handler can't be set automatically. Instead, you need to use the Auto_Open macro. An Auto_Open macro can only work in an add-in. This is only daunting the first time you do it, the class module and add-in can be quite simple. Here are some pages with more info about PowerPoint event programming: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=327 http://officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html

Comment: The simplest approach I can think of would be to have any code that you run include ActivePresentation.Saved=True at the end of the routine and then have your own Quit button that sets Saved=True again and closes the presentation. With Saved=True the user won't be prompted to save the presentation, so any changes made during the slideshow would be discareded.